# how to upload image to page without clicking save button and also avoid refreshing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

actully i am using a control for two image uploading but i want to change the image by clicking on browse button without click on saving button i want the browsed image to be stable but it is disappear while selecting any dropdown means while page refreshing it disapper?i am using the following code :

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
        <!-- Place updatable markup and controls here. -->
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Use AjaxToolkit's FileUpload : http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

Comment: please see uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/